# difference in execution of a script in bash and korn

Tags: bash, unix, while-loop

i have a script that reads a file line by line 
the code is

```
FILE=commands.txt
while read CMD; do
    echo "$CMD"
done < "$FILE"
```

This code is stored in a script file vxm_alarm.sh
In Korn shell, this loop works perfectly, when i run the command `vxm_alarm.sh`. In bash however i get the following error

```
vxm_alarm.sh: syntax error at line 4: `done' unexpected
```

In Bash I'm executing the script using the command `sh vxm_alarm.sh`. what am i doing wrong? And why can't we execute a script simply by doing this in bash

```
chmod +x filename.sh
filename.sh
```

Comment: Are you sure you've not missed the semi-colon after the `while` command. I accidentally missed it and was able to reproduce your issue

Comment: nope. I have put the semi colon. Like i said the code worked in Korn, but the same code is not working in Bash

Comment: You are not using bash but the legacy Bourne shell with this command: `sh vxm_alarm.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works on my machine using GNU bash 4.1.5

Try adding a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) to the top:

```
#!/bin/sh
FILE=commands.txt
while read CMD; do
    echo "$CMD"
done < "$FILE"
```

Comment: GNU bash, version 3.00.16(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.10) is my version.

Comment: im still getting the same error even after adding a shebang.. done not expected

Comment: `/bin/sh` != `/bin/bash`, especially on Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `sh vxm_alarm.sh` you are most likely not running Bash. Try `sh --version` - If you get anything other than a version string, it's *not* Bash. Try running `bash vxm_alarm.sh` instead.

To be able to run a script without a path before it it has to be in one of the directories listed in the `PATH` variable. For example, if

```
echo "$PATH"
```

prints

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

you can put `filename.sh` in `/usr/local/sbin`, `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/sbin`, `/usr/bin`, `/sbin` or `/bin` and run it as simply `filename.sh`. If you want your script to be run from a directory not in the path, you have three choices:

1. Modify `$PATH` to include the directory where the script resides.
2. Run it with a relative or absolute path.
3. Create an alias or function pointing to the relative or absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to answer this part of your question:

> why can't we execute a script simply by doing this in bash
>
> ```
> chmod +x filename.sh
> filename.sh
> ```

As others already pointed out in part, there are several things required for that to work:

1. execution rights (You ensured that with your `chmod` command)
2. the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), so the system knows what shell/interpreter to use

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   ```

   (it is important to say **bash** if you want *bash* and not *sh*)
3. make sure the command is found. This is the case when its directory is found in `PATH`. However what you'd rather do in this case is specify the directory. For the current directory you can do it like this

   ```
   ./name-of-the-script
   ```

   In contrast to DOS and (IIRC) the various Windows Command line interfaces, Unix systems usually don't have the current directory on the `PATH`. It is possible to add it, but discouraged due to severe implications on security.